# Does the limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3-y^3}{3x+2y}$ exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does this limit exist? $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3-y^3}{3x+2y}$$

From what I understand, the line $3x+2y=0$ goes through $(0,0)$, so the limit doesn't exist.
But shouldn't I be able to find two paths with different limits in that case? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: The trick in these cases, when we want to show that the limit doesn't exist, is to approach along a path such that the main part of $3x+2y$ is equal to zero but we keep some remainder which determine the value for the denominator in such way that the limit takes a different values. In this case we can choose for $x=t \to 0$and then $y=-\frac32 t+t^n$. We need to choose $n$ in such way to obtain a different limit from the trivail one obtained for the path with $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the points such that $3x+2y=0$ are simply excluded from the domain and thus we can't conclude that the limit doesn't exist from here.

To show that we need to find two different paths with different limits as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.

Notably in this case we have that

- for $x=y$ we have $\dfrac{x^3-y^3}{3x+2y}=0$
- for $x=t\to 0$ and $y=-\frac32t+t^3$ we have $=\dfrac{x^3-y^3}{3x+2y}=\dfrac{t^3-(-\frac32t+t^3)^3}{3t-3t+2t^3}\to L\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: What I meant by 3x+2y=0 is that the function tends to + or -infinity near those points, so I assume the delta-epsilon definition would fail.
Anyway, thank you very much. This helped a lot.

Comment: @Manuel It is not a reason to conclude that the limit doesn't exist. What about, for example, for $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin xy}{xy}$?

Comment: @Manuel Note also that, usually, when we refer to the existence of the limit we mean that the limit is the same (finite or infinite) for any path. Therefore to show that the limit doesn't exist it suffices to find (at least) two different paths with different limits.

Comment: I'd say your example is a different situation, because at the points where the denominator = 0, your function approaches 1.

Comment: @Manuel And what about $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{1}{x^2y^2}$?

Comment: I see your point. I forgot to mention that in my original question I had already found a path with limit 0, so I knew that the limit was not infinite.

Comment: @Manuel That's ok, now we need to show a second path with a different limit (finite or infinite).

Answer (score 1):

Go along curves $y=ax+bx^3$ for suitable $a$ and $b$.