# Calculus of $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{8 x^2 y^3 }{x^9+y^3} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, rational-functions

By Wolfram Alpha I know that the limit
$$
   \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{8 x^2 y^3 }{x^9+y^3}=0.
$$
I have tried to prove that this limit is $0$, by using polar coordinate, the AM–GM inequality and the change of variable $ x^9= r^2 \cos^2(t) $ and $y^3= r^2 \sin^2(t)$, but these attempts were unsatisfactory.

I also have reviewed the similar questions and their answers but there are difference between those functions and mine one, I think the principal difference is that the powers of the denominators are odd.

Comment: What happens on (or near) the curve $y=-x^3$? Observe that this curve passes through the origin.

Comment: The presence of odd powers in the denominator spells trouble, well spotted. Wonder why WA fumbled this one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Is that WA error because of ordered limits exist? i.e. $\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}=\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}=0!!$

Comment: If that was not convincing enough, try $y=-x^3+A x^5$ with different choices for the constant $A$.

Comment: @C.F.G That is a live possibility! A great observation.

Comment: @C.F.G However WA finds correctly that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} xy/(x^2+y^2)$ is undefined...

Comment: Dowonvotes to six digit rep users posting banalities instead of guiding the student to do their own work.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't know if downvoting is supposed to be used that way, but I agree. It's pretty lame .Even though a correct answer may be given, sometimes it's basically pointless.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My answer was aimed to continue the hints given in the comments. The guide here is to give an example on how conclude the problem with these suggestion (in my answer it is not concluded at all, some more step is needed). If you have some other way to help the asker, the best way should be posting a better answer, downvoting users is not effective for the asker in order to learn more or create useful content for the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, that function isn't even bounded near $(0,0)$ and therefore, the limit at that point doesn't exist. You can check that$$\frac{8x^2(-x^3+x^6)^3}{x^9+(-x^3+x^6)^3}=\frac{8 \left(x^3-1\right)^3}{x \left(x^6-3 x^3+3\right)}$$and that$$\lim_{x\to0}\left|\frac{8 \left(x^3-1\right)^3}{x \left(x^6-3 x^3+3\right)}\right|=\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you so much because your explanation. The last thing I do not understand is why Wolfram Alpha says this limit is 0. ¿Any idea? ¿Any advice for recognize when the software fails?

Comment: Perhaps that Wolfrom Alpha got it wrong by the reason posted in a comment to your question by C.F.G: if $f$ is your function, $\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)=\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}f(x,y)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, let consider the following path "near" the problematic points $y=-x^3$ for which denominator vanishes:

- $x=t$
- $y=-t^3+t^5$

then we have

$$\frac{8 x^2 y^3 }{x^9+y^3}
=\dfrac{8 t^2 (-t^3+t^5)^3 }{t^9+(-t^3+t^5)^3}
=\frac{8 t^2(-t^{9}+3t^{11}-3t^{13}+t^{15})}{t^9+(-t^{9}+3t^{11}-3t^{13}+t^{15})}=\\
=8\frac{-t^{11}+3t^{13}-3t^{15}+t^{17}}{3t^{11}-3t^{13}+t^{15}}=8\frac{-1+3t^2-3t^{4}+t^{6}}{3-3t^{2}+t^{4}}$$

For the general strategy, see also the related:

- [Find $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin (xy)}{x+y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459850/505767)

Comment: An error in the expansion of the cube in the denominator. The terms in $(-t^3+t^5)^3$ have degrees $9,11,13$ and $15$ respectively. My hint was designed specifically to make the degree $11$ term to be the leading "surviving" term in the denominator, yielding a non-zero limit along those curves.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes of course, I did it mentally and went wrong. Thanks I fix that.